# Electron preload script for webview not working?

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I have this webview that I load like this:

```
<webview id="link-view"
        src="http://url.espace.com/"
        preload="./preload.js"
        autosize="on"
        partition="persist:link"></webview>
```

In the preload.js file : I have this

```
console.log("test");
```

This doesn't even work..

Can someone explain?

Comment: Try to use `preload.js` instead of `./preloads.js`.

Comment: To those coming from Google, make sure that when you create the webview dynamically, use setAttribute. This confused me a little, because it used to work with older versions of Electron. So instead of webview.preload = './preload.js' do webview.setAttribute('preload', './preload.js')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just tried the same scenario, and it worked as expected.

Do you have the `<webview>` dev tools open? As a `<webview>`has its own dev tools, That would be the only reason i can see for the preload script not showing the `console.log` output. They can be opened by:

```
var webview = document.getElementById("link-view");
webview.openDevTools();
```

Or your path to the script is incorrect, which i doubt as you seem sure about that.

Comment: If this doesn't work for anyone, then most likely something in the preload script itself is getting an error, which _won't_ be displayed in the app dev tools, but instead the webview one.

Answer (score 4):

Using latest [Electron 2.0.0](https://electronjs.org) (`beta-5`, at the time of this writing), the `preload` attribute demands a `file:` (or `asar:`) protocol followed by an absolute path. Paths such as `./preload.js` don't seem to work anymore and raise an exception: `Only "file:" protocol is supported in "preload" attribute.`

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem in electron 3.0.0-beta.4 using react.js

```
<webview src={'http://example.com'} preload={`file://${__dirname}/preload.js`}/>
```